# How to control elements in dynamically created columns in a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I created several dynamic columns of checkbox using this code upon pageload:

```
 For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim checkbox1 As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(row.Cells.Count - 1).Controls(0), CheckBox)
            checkbox1.Enabled = True
  Next
```

Now, I need to programmatically check some checkbox inside the gridview. This is the code I'm using:

```
 Dim check_rtd As CheckBox = DirectCast(row_a.FindControl("checkbox1"), CheckBox)
 'If a condition is met:
  checkbox1.Checked = True
```

But this error occurs:

```
 Object Reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Any idea? Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

Since `check_rtd` is declared as `CheckBox` and using `DirectCast` you are assigning `checkbox1` to `check_rtd` so you need to use `check_rtd`

So replace this code

```
 Dim check_rtd As CheckBox = DirectCast(row_a.FindControl("checkbox1"), CheckBox)
 checkbox1.Checked = True
```

with

```
 Dim check_rtd As CheckBox = DirectCast(row_a.FindControl("checkbox1"), CheckBox)
 'If a condition is met:
  check_rtd .Checked = True
```

Comment: hi Neethu! I just tried replacing the code, and it is still not working. :(